# Combining cells unless a cell contains certain text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 7 cells (in a column) with data in, these are C13 to C19
I have a formula that combines all the data in these cells together and puts it into one cell, this formula is ***=C13&", "&C14&", "&C15&", "&C16&", "&C17&", "&C18&", "&C19*** and works fine.  However, can I alter this formula to miss out on any cell that contains the text "Nothing else carby"?

Comment: You can use `TEXTJOIN()` if you have `Excel2019` or `Excel365`.

Comment: You can check every single one with IF combined with COUNTIF if they contain the text `Nothing else carby` using wildcards `*`. If the count is 0, return cell & ",". IF count is not 0, then return nothing "". And then combine all cells into one. Indeed a long formula.

Comment: Thank you @Foxfire And Burns And Burns - I do have Excel 2019, how would that formula be written out please?

Comment: If you have Excel2019, then try TEXTJOIN. I do not have it here so can't help. But to check a single cell, if would be something like `IF(COUNTIF(C13;"*"&"Nothing else carby"&"*")=0;C13&", ";"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula should not be that long, as you can see:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(C13:C19="Nothing","", C13:C19))
```

(I just used "Nothing" instead of the whole word for readability reasons.)

Explanation of the parameters:

```
"," : delimiter: between every cell content, a comma is added.
TRUE : treatment of blank cells (don't put them).
IF (...) : In case cell content is "Nothing", put an empty string. 
           In combination with the previous parameter,
           just one comma will be put in the result:
           "a,b,c,e,f,g" and not "a,b,c,,e,f,g" (see result).
```

Used data:

```
a
b
c
Nothing
e
f
g
```

Result:

```
a,b,c,e,f,g
```

Comment: In case you find my answer useful, you might upvote it (not accept, you can only accept one answer).

Answer (score 1):

You may, in Excel 2019, use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(C13:C19<>"Nothing else carby",C13:C19,""))
```

If "Nothing else carby" can be a substring inside a cell's value, try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Nothing else carby",C13:C19)),"",C13:C19))
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Nice one!!! Did not though about using FIND and ISNUMBER. Upvoted